# React routing: Switch not working as expected with id_token

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-router, url-routing, access-token

I use the following routing statement in React:

```
  <Switch>
     <Redirect from="/start" to="/xyz" />                            
     <Route path="/xyz" component={MyTab} />
     <Route exact path="**" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

Now, in my browser I go to the */start* path with a hash fragment. What I observe is:

- when the hash fragment has only **state**
  (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/start#state=ABC`), I end up in the
  MyTab, as expected.
- when the hash fragment has both **state** and
  **id_token** (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/start#state=ABC&id_token=PQR`), I end up in
  NotFound, *unlike expected*.

Why and how to make also the second case end up in MyTab?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
 <Switch>
     <Route path="/start" component={MyTab} />                          
     <Route path="/xyz" component={MyTab} />
     <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't! And anyway, I want to have this redirect, not route.